# Axios get with params

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I am trying to implement getting data from API with params. I got two functions for that and I can't see the error. Any ideas?

```
getFilteredProducts() {
    return apiClient.get('/product/', {
      params: {
        search: String(name)
      }
    })
  }
```

```
async fetchFilteredProducts({ commit }, name) {
      await productService.getFilteredProducts({name})
      .then(response => {
        commit('SET_FILTERED_PRODUCTS', response.data.items)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error has occured' + error)
      })
    }
```

I received working solutions with the code below, so the problem probably with the second parameter.

```
async fetchFilteredProducts({ commit }, name) {
      await axios.get("MY_API_URL/product/", {
        params: {
          search: String(name)
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        commit('SET_FILTERED_PRODUCTS', response.data.items)
      })
```

Comment: You haven't told us what errors you see, what URL is generated, what URL you were trying to generate. It's really hard to identify the problem here, let along its cause or the solution.

Comment: I have no error in the browser, the loader is appearing because of API request but I don't have any result like using Axios.get directly.

Comment: Why are you using async-await and `.then()` after that?

Comment: You try to pass parameters to the `getFilteredProducts` function but it doesn't accept any

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not clear about what you are trying to accomplish but I think your functions should be like this:

**Using Async/Await:**

```js
// Your Service
async getFilteredProducts(name) {
  return await apiClient.get('/product/', {
    params: {
      search: String(name)
    }
  })
}

// Using Your Service
async someParentFunction() {
    const response = await getFilteredProducts("John")
    console.log(response.data);
}
```

**Using Promises:**

```js
// Your Service
getFilteredProducts(name) {
  return apiClient.get('/product/', {
    params: {
      search: String(name)
    }
  })
}

// Using Your Service
getFilteredProducts("John").then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
})
```

Do note the `name` parameter which I am passing to `getFilteredProducts` method. Previously this wasn't there so `String(name)` would result in an empty string `""`.